# Acrescentar extensão .html ao final de todos os links em vários arquivos (com Shell Script)

Tags: html, regex, shell-script, sed

Olá.

Eu tenho uma grande quantidade de arquivos HTML que possuem links no seguinte formato: `http://localhost:8080/tag:alguma_coisa` e eu preciso acrescentar a extensão `.html` a esses links para que fiquem assim: `http://localhost:8080/tag:alguma_coisa.html`.

Já tentei diversas combinações com `find`e `sed` mas com nenhuma delas consegui o resultado esperado.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso com Shell Script?

Comment: O conteúdo desses arquivos são somente links? Ou há outra coisas (comentários, linhas em branco, etc...)?

Comment: É código fonte HTML. O que preciso é pegar todas os atributos das tags html que sejam no formato `nome_atributo="tag:algumacoisa"` e trocar por `nome_atributo="tag:algumacoisa.html"`. Por exemplo, tenho `<a href="tag:city">` e preciso trocar por `<a href="tag>city.html">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com a ajuda do Marcelodez no tópico [do VOL](http://find%20$OUTPUTDIR%20-type%20f%20-name%20%22*.html%22%20%7C%20xargs%20sed%20-i%20's/href/%5Cnhref/g'%20#%20quebra%20todos%20as%20tag%20A%20para%20que%20href%20comece%20uma%20nova%20linha%20find%20$OUTPUTDIR%20-type%20f%20-name%20%22*.html%22%20%7C%20xargs%20sed%20-i%20'/%5Ehref=%22.*tag:.*[%5E#]/%20s/%22/.html%22/2'%20#%20coloca%20.html%20ao%20final%20do%20valor%20de%20href%20para%20links%20com%20padr%C3%A3o%20tag:*%20mas%20que%20n%C3%A3o%20tem%20#%20find%20$OUTPUTDIR%20-type%20f%20-name%20%22*.html%22%20%7C%20xargs%20sed%20-i%20'/%5Ehref=%22.*tag:.*#/%20s/#/.html#/1'%20#%20coloca%20.html%20antes%20do%20#%20para%20links%20no%20padr%C3%A3o%20tag:*%20com%20#%20find%20$OUTPUTDIR%20-type%20f%20-name%20%22*.html%22%20%7C%20xargs%20sed%20-i%20'/%3Ca/%20N;s/%5Cn//'%20#%20junta%20href%20nba%20mesma%20linha%20de%20tag):

```js
# Ajusta os links para arquivos tag:* colocando .html ao final
# Com a importante ajudade de Marcelodez no tópico https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/Sed-Awk-ER-Manipulacao-de-Textos-Strings/Acrescentar-extensao-html-ao-final-de-todos-os-links-em-varios-arquivos-com-Shell-Script/
find $OUTPUTDIR -type f -name "*.html" | xargs sed -i 's/href/\nhref/g' # quebra todos as tag A para que href comece uma nova linha
find $OUTPUTDIR -type f -name "*.html" | xargs sed -i '/^href=".*tag:.*[^#]/ s/"/.html"/2' # coloca .html ao final do valor de href para links com padrão tag:* mas que não tem #
find $OUTPUTDIR -type f -name "*.html" | xargs sed -i '/^href=".*tag:.*#/ s/#/.html#/1' # coloca .html antes do # para links no padrão tag:* com #
find $OUTPUTDIR -type f -name "*.html" | xargs sed -i '/<a/ N;s/\n//' # junta href nba mesma linha de tag
```

Answer (score 1):

Considerando arquivos no diretório atual no formato .html e que dentro desses arquivos há apenas links, ficaria assim:

```
find . -type f -name *.html -exec sed 's/$/.html/g' {} \;
```

Comment: Usei o comando `find . -type f -name "*.htm" -exec sed '/tag:.*"/ s/tag:.*"/&.html/g' {} \;` e foi o mais próximo que consegui, pois o resultado foi o seguinte: O padrão original era `<a href="tag:city">city</a>` e eu consegui colocar o `.html`no fim, deste jeito: `<a href="tag:city".html>city</a>`. O problema é que ele ficou fora das aspas.